# Can AngularDart and Zurb Foundation work together?

Tags: dart, zurb-foundation, angular-dart

I want to use AngularDart and CSS framework, more specifically Zurb Foundation, for responsive applications. I do not want to use Bootstrap (for some reason).

Can AngularDart and Zurb Foundation work out of the box? What are the workarounds, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular.dart you can declare if you want to create components with or without shadowDOM. Existing CSS frameworks usually won't work with shadowDOM. As long as you set `useShadowDom` to `false` for your components you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

angular.dart and angularjs works with HTML.
You can use any CSS framework you want, Bootstrap or Zurb Foundation.
You might need to be careful when using javascript plugins because angular need to know about the state of elements.